# Homebrew install: error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: error:06FFF064:digital envelope routines:CRYPTO_internal:bad decrypt, errno 0

Tags: git, homebrew, macos-monterey

Am trying to install `homebrew` on a Macbook pro Apple M1 with MacOS Monterey but it always fails at this step as shown below.

```
HEAD is now at 472edc06e Merge pull request #12943 from Homebrew/update-man- 
completions
==> Tapping homebrew/core
remote: Enumerating objects: 1150006, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (29/29), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: error:06FFF064:digital envelope 
routines:CRYPTO_internal:bad decrypt, errno 0
error: 1835 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
Failed during: git fetch --force origin 
refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

I have tried setting my git global username like this

```
git config --global user.email yourgitemail@example.com
```

To deleting homebrew and trying a fresh install like this

```
sudo rm -fr /opt/homebrew
```

To increasing the buffer size

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

With no success. Nothing seem to work for me.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the commands that you listed I also run these instructions:

```
git config --global --add remote.origin.proxy ""
git config --global http.sslVerify "false"
```

After running `sudo rm -fr /opt/homebrew` (in order to clean for previous attempts) I got it to work fine.

Comment: I was able to get this working again by just removing the proxy, and leaving `sslVerify` alone.